# Execute a python separate application in a java application

Tags: java, python, postgresql, native

I have a small java project which do several activities including a database update and i have a separate python(.py) application which update the same database after a data mining process. In my Java application i need to open(execute) my python application which update the same database. i tried several ways but the code is not working. below i paste the initial code without calling the .py file.

```
 if (getDB("BP") != 0.0 && getDB("BT") != 0.0 &&
     getDB("SO2") != 0.0 && getDB("HR") != 0.0) {
             if(analyzeData(inputLine)) {
                setDB(inputLine);
        //<python(.py) file should execute independently in this section, after setDB(inputLine)>
             } } 
             else { 
                  setNormalBio(inputLine); 
                  }
```

Comment: Did you try something like that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192595/running-shell-or-system-command-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see anything related to spawning a new process from your java code. Did you really investigate this topic? If not: Do not expect the following code to be the top-notch solution. Maybe dig deeper in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html and the python docs, as I remember, when I did this from PHP, I ran into some problems with the python code itself.

Python (deadparrot.py):

```
from os import chdir, name as osname
from os.path import dirname, abspath

def voom():
    if osname == 'posix':
        chdir(dirname(abspath(__file__)))
    return "Testing! This is your nine o'clock alarm call!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print voom()
    exit(0)
```

I am not sure with the chdir-call. Once got a project, in which I needed to call python in a linux webserver environment with php (hence the 'posix'), and doing stuff with relative pathes in the python-script. IIRC I didn't need it while testing on my local windows-environment.
Edit 1: I tested it in Windows 7. It looks like neither pb.directory(...) or chdir(...) is needed, to call relativ pathes from the python script. IDK about linux.
About the '**__main__**' condition. I am using this, because this way I still can call the script from the java-app (exit(0) returns an ok in unix-terminology) and in addition use the voom() function from another python-script, like so:

```
from deadparrot import voom

voom()
```

Java:

```
package test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestJavaAppClean {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProcessBuilder pb = null;
        Process p = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;

        try {
            String top = "C:\\Users\\MaxMueller\\Documents\\test\\";
            String cmd = "C:\\Python27\\python.exe";
            String arg = "deadparrot.py";
            pb = new ProcessBuilder(new String[]{cmd, top + arg});
            pb.directory(new File(top));
            p = pb.start();
            br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(line);
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        } finally {
            try {
                if (br != null) {
                    br.close();
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
            }
            if (p != null) {
                p.destroy();
            }
        }
    }
}
```