# How to send terminal commands

Tags: java

I want to send terminal commands to the machine running the jar file, i know in some other languages like shell and python i think its something like this
`run("cmd here")`

Thanks

Also, i have read some previous posts here and they all seem to be for the windows command line.

I have not tried anything else yet as i do not know where to start, one thing i tried was using Jsch but that ended up being a giant program and i think its kind of unsatisfying when you need to input your machines details over and over again, even so most machines do not come pre equipped with SSH.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running Shell or System Command in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7192595/running-shell-or-system-command-in-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to execute the command, use

```
Runtime.getRuntime.exec(command);
```

where `command` is the command you want to execute as String.
If you want to read/write from/to `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr`, you can use the returned `Process`es methods `getOutputStram()`, `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()`.

Note that `getInputStream()` and `getErrorStream()` are for `stdout` and `stderr` while `getOutputStream()` is for `stdin`.